# Can I collect data on shiny?

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server

I want to build a small webapplication with the R package shiny, where users enter data about things like their country of origin and the like. Then the application continuously updates measures like number of users from this country and so on.

Can I host and build up the data directly on the shiny server or would I need to externally handle the user input?

Comment: Do you own/administer the Shiny server? I have done this on one I control (involves no SQL, BTW).

Answer (score 0):

You would need to create a SQL database on your server, then use RMySQL to insert/update your tables based on user input.